# Can i host google chrome extensions on my site

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I have created one Google chrome extension for my site. I need to be installed this extension automatically while I am running my webpage on browser.. I want to place the packed extension in my own site. is it's possible to host my extension in my own site. Please advice me how I can install that extension automatically while I am running my page and also how it is possible to host in my own server.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Inline Installation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation) for users to easily install your app.

You can create a simple popup that redirect to the site with code as follows

```
<div id="p2r_addon_inst" class="myclass">
    <div id="chrome_info" style="display: block; top: 0px;">
        <div id="addon_install_icon"></div>
        <span id="addon_install_message">Chrome extension is available for this site <a href="your link">More info...</a> </span>
        <div id="addon_install_buttonblock">
            <div id="addon_install_remove"></div>
            <button id="addon_install_extinstallbutton">Install</button>
            <button id="addon_install_dontaskagain">Don't ask again</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css is

```
.myclass{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
overflow: visible;
z-index: 999;
}
```